# Encapsulating templated field accessor

Tags: c++, oop, templates, encapsulation

Suppose we have the following:

```
class Item {
protected:
    template <typename T>
    Field<T>& getField(const String& fieldName);
    template <typename T>
    const Field<T>& getField(const String& fieldName) const;
};

template <typename T>
class Field {
public:
    using data_t = T;
    const String& getName() const;
    data_t getValue() const;
    void setValue(data_t&);
};

class File : public Item{
public: // There are also setters
    String getFileName() const {
        return getField<String>("file_name").getValue();
    }

    Integer getFileSize() const {
        return getField<Integer>("file_size").getValue();
    }
}

class Folder : public Item{
public:
    String getFolderName() const {
        return getField<String>("folder_name").getValue();
    }
}
```

The fields can be mapped from name and types in a JSON object:

```
String fileName = json.GetString("file_size");
file.setFileName(fileName);
Integer fileSize = json.GetInt("file_size");
file.setFileSize(fileSize);
```

I would like to simplify this boiler plate down to:

```
parse<File::file_name>(json, file)
parse<File::file_size>(json, file)
```

In other words, let compiler figure out the type of a field, given its name (as a type).

So I did the following:

```
class File : public Mixin<Item, PropertyAccessor> {
public:
    struct file_name { // Generated with a macro
        using type = String;
        static const String& getFieldName() {
            static String fieldName = "file_name"
            return fieldName;
        }
    }

    struct file_size {
        using type = Integer;
        static const String& getFieldName() {
            static String fieldName = "file_size"
            return fieldName;
        }
    }
}

class PropertyAccessor {
    template <typename Property>
    typename Property::type get() const; // Arcane inside

    template <typename Property>
    void set(typename Property::type&);
}
```

The good news is that it is possible to do the following:

```
auto fileName = file.get<file_name>();  // fileName is String
file.set<file_size>(5);                 // Works as long as 5 is convertible to Integer
```

The problem, however, is that the encapsulation is broken:

```
file.get<folder_name>(); // Guaranteed tragedy if implementation is left as is
```

Moreover, anyone can define a dummy struct to access the fields (and potentially with a wrong type).

Now, my question is: is this design a good idea? if so, how would you fix the encapsulation?

(I think it is possible to fix the encapsulation by defining hierarchy among the properties, using template and inheritance.
So that PropertyAccessor can only access properties defined by the item's current type or its parents,
while other accesses will be a compile time error)

Edit: `Item` is not simply a wrapper around an JSON object, although JSON is one of the possible sources of field value (other possible sources include XML, loading from database etc..). Wording in the original question is changed to avoid confusion.

For simplicity's sake, `Item::getField<T>(const String&)` is backed by a `map<String, unique_ptr<Field<T>>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that you do not provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (especially: missing implementation for getField), so it is difficult to give a good answer; still I try from the information you provide.

*Edit: completely reworked the answer...*

Comparing your first approach to the second, while trying to spare the explicit getters (and setters?), you are introducing new inner classes and an additional template class. My personally feeling with this: You did not gain anything, but made the interface and the class itself more complex and difficult to understand and use (compare `file.getFileName()` to `file.get<File::file_name>()`), together with all the problems you describe.

So personally would rather stick with the first approach. An idea to make the work a little simpler could be the following. I renamed the original Field to Data, because I prefer the name 'Field' for what I used it for. Feel free to find any better names for both (if you like the idea at all...):

```cpp
template < typename T >
class Data
{
public:
    using data_t = T;
    const String& getName() const;
    data_t getValue() const;
    void setValue(data_t&);
};

class Item
{
private:
    template < typename T >
    friend class Field;
    template <typename T>
    Data<T>& getField(const String& fieldName);
    template <typename T>
    const Data<T>& getField(const String& fieldName) const;
};

template < typename T >
class Field
{
    Item& parent;
    String name;
public:
    Field(Item& parent, String const& name)
            : parent(parent), name(name)
    { }
    String const& getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    T getValue() const
    {
        return parent.getField<T>(name).getValue();
    }
    operator T() const
    {
        return getValue();
    }
};
class File : public Item
{
public:
    Field<String> name;
    Field<Integer> size;

    File()
        : Item(),
          name(*this, "file_name"),
          size(*this, "file_size")
    { }
};
class Folder : public Item
{
public:
    Field<String> name;

    Folder()
        : Item();
          name(*this, "folder_name")
    { }
};
```

Could then be used like this:

```cpp
File file;
Folder folder;
String s(file.name);
Integer i(file.size);
s = folder.name;
```

Might yet be an improvement to make either both Data and Field or at least Field (the new one) an inner class of Item. Field could possibly be inherited by another template class EditableField providing the setter, so you are free to decide which fields are editable or not, according to the template type used. Have not yet worked out the latter idea, though.

Comment: The question has been edited. Personally I would disagree that a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example" is needed for this question. The question is not about a bug in the program, but a design decision. That being said, I am sorry about my misleading wording and partial information.

Comment: Interesting idea. In a sister project of the one I'm working on, an implementation similar to yours was adopted. In that project a copy of `data` is separately stored to provide faster access to certain "constant" fields (i.e. primary key).

Comment: One complaint I may have is that each `File` object would internally store two additional `String`s in runtime. Not something I really mind, as a `File` generally has 80+ entries...

Comment: If you had global constants (`String const FileName("file_name");`) for every property existing, you could use these to initialise the Field's name member, which then could be a simple reference - and the problem is gone...